# Jump to a column

Tags: excel, vba

Quite new to VBA and wasn't sure on a specific piece of code

I wanted to run a macro which goes to a specific column, cuts it, and moves it to the beginning of the sheet

The columns are:

```
AFG1
XW1
AMY1
NH1
```

So by the end, each of these will be in Columns A,B,C,D

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the macro recorder yet?

Comment: yes, for some reason it didnt work/pick up the code. The file its referring to is a CSV, not sure if this impacts it, so wanted to write it out instead

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this is what you want, but I recorded macro that cuts column L and paste it to the beginning of the sheet.

```
Columns("L:L").Select
Selection.Cut
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
```

Which simplifies to:

```
ActiveSheet.Columns("L:L").Cut
ActiveSheet.Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
```

Comment: thats perfect, many thanks!

Comment: Then you can mark it as Answer